# How to take only first line from the multiline text

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get only the first line of multiline text using regular expressions?

```
        string test = @"just take this first line
        even there is 
        some more
        lines here";

        Match m = Regex.Match(test, "^", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        if (m.Success)
            Console.Write(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string test = @"just take this first line
even there is 
some more
lines here";

Match m = Regex.Match(test, "^(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (m.Success)
    Console.Write(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

`.` is often touted to match any character, while this isn't totally true. `.` matches any character only if you use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. Without this option, it matches any character except for `'\n'` (end of line).

<strike>That said, a better option is likely to be:</strike>

```
string test = @"just take this first line
even there is 
some more
lines here";

string firstLine = test.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

And better yet, is Brian Rasmussen's version:

```
string firstline = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: Your alternative solution does a lot of work that isn't really necessary. If test is short as in the example it probably isn't going to be a problem, but for a big multi-line string it is a bit of waste.

Comment: @Brian, I agree. I didn't change it to copy yours in the hopes that yours would be accepted, but I think I might 'borrow' it now.

Comment: In Windows, the given test string contains both carriage return and new lines (`"\r\n"`) at the end of each line. Using the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option with `"^(.*)"` includes the carriage return at the end of the string in the captured group. Use `"^([^\r]*)"` instead if you don't want that. (Assuming you can guarantee that `'\r'` only ever occurs in the expected place, i.e. with an accompanying `'\n'`).

Comment: @BrianRasmussen's solution (quoted in this answer) will This will throw an `Exception` if the input string doesn't contain a newline character!

Answer (score 40):

If you just need the first line, you can do it without using a regex like this

```
var firstline = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

As much as I like regexs, you don't really need them for everything, so unless this is part of some larger regex exercise, I would go for the simpler solution in this case.

Comment: Please comment when down voting.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm the person who upvoted you) But it's probably because it's not a regex.

Comment: This is the best solution. No regex needed for a such a simple task, and this is also efficient.

Comment: @Matthew: true, but shouldn't we allow for useful alternatives as well when answering?

Comment: The question is " How to do it WITH regex" so you can't know why author needs this and you answer WITHOUT regex can be completely useless.

Comment: @Restuta: Fair point, but personally I would still find an answer like the one I provided useful, as it provides an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: what if the text can potentially come from another environment? e.g. mail text body.

Comment: If the initial string only has one line, then this will pass -1 as the length argument into the Substring call. Instead, it should not substring single line strings.

Comment: @Douglas The question specifically states multiline input.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Probably worth a warning that this method won't accept an arbitrary string. For example, if someone uses it as a function to return the first line of user input, it might work most of the time, but will throw if the input happens to be one line.

Comment: I get -1 for the NewLine index when I use this solution.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Then your input probably doesn't contain Environment.NewLine. Remember, different platforms treat new lines differently.

Comment: If there is only a single line in a multi-line text then this results in ArgumentOutOfRangeException. You will need to check for existence first if you go this route...

Comment: This will throw an `Exception` if the input string doesn't contain a newline character!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(test, @".*\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of line replaces rest of text after linefeed with empty string.

```
test = Regex.Replace(test, "(\n.*)$", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This will work also properly if string does not have linefeed - then no replacement will be done.