# Regex to select all commas up to a specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a terrible time with regular expressions. Its terrible for me to admit, but I just don't use them enough to be really good when I need to be. Basically due to the way our application runs, I have the contents of a .csv file pulled out into a string. I need to essentially insert a new row above and below what already exists. The amount of columns can change depending on the report. What I would like to do is grab all commas without any other characters (including whitespace) up to the first set of \r\n in the string. This way I have all the columns and I can insert a blank row up top and populate the columns with what I need.  Here is an example of the .csv text:

```
"Date, Account Code, Description, Amount\r\n23-Apr-13,12345,Account1,$12345\r\n"
```

What I would like the regex to grab:

```
",,," or ",,,\r\n"
```

I just cannot seem to get this. Thank you.

Comment: I'd use a `Regex.Replace` instead and replace the pattern "[^\,]" with "".

Comment: Another trival solution is to just grab the line and then split it on , and count the tokens.

Comment: Adrian, that gets all commas, not just up to the \r\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this.

```
string firstLine = file.ReadLines().First();
int numCommas = firstLine.Count(c => c == ',');
string commaString = new String(',', numCommas);
```

If you don't have access to `file.ReadLines()` method, you can use the following from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576999/how-to-take-only-first-line-from-the-multiline-text):

```
string firstline = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to complicate your code with Regular Epressions to accomplish what you want: to count the columns.

Here's an extremely simple method:

```
String textline = csvtext.Substring(0, csvtext.IndexOfAny(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()));
int columns = textline.Split(',').Length;
```

Now the `columns` variable has your total number of columns.

---

The first line grabs *just* the first line out of the CSV text. The second line splits that text into an array separated by commas (`,`), and returns the total number.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use the below regex
`(?<=[\d\w\s])(\r|\n|,)(?=[\d\w\s\W])`
to match , and new line characters,
Use can make use of `Regex.Replace("inputstring","regexpattern","replacechar", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

This can be done by string operations itself

```
string[] strs= inputstr.split(new string[]{"\n","\r",","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string str in strs)
{
// do you part
}
```